# Auto Associate Related Work Items to Pull Request via Azure CLI

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli

When a pull request is created using the Azure Devops website, it automatically associates related work items for the commits to be merged. However, when a pull request is created using the Azure CLI (`az repos pr create`) the work items are not associated.

Is there a way to automatically associate the works items via the Azure CLI? They can be manually associated with `az repos pr work-item add`, but I'm hoping there is a way to have it happen automatically like the site does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not now. There is a bug for this behaviour: [[Bug] Different Behavior on "az repos pr create" and web interface](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/issues/1038).